# Shiny application successfully deployed but opens to "Error : You must register an account using setAccountInfo prior to proceeding."

Tags: ios, shiny

I successfully deployed my first app following the the instructions on http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html.

I then successfully deployed my second app.

I decided to make some changes to my first application. I archived and deleted the application, created a new R file of the app and then tried to deploy it. Everything works well and I see the following message in the "Deploy" window:

Application successfully deployed to https://hessamss2.shinyapps.io/icu_infection

However, when the app page pops up, what I see is the following error message:
"ERROR: You must register an account using setAccountInfo prior to proceeding."

Comment: Have you checked the output to `rsconnect::showLogs()`? I suspect the problem is you are making a call to `deployApp()` in your `server.R`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Removed the deployApp() and now it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='', token='', secret='')` line first before deploying the app.

You can find this code at https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/tokens in your shiny app account